# Как найти предел представимых значений для целочисленного типа данных javascript?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, типы-данных

Экспериментальным путем определил, что в javascript после некоторого значения, переменная представляется как infinity или -infinity. Можно ли написать алгоритм (только арифметические операторы) выводящий такое число, что с прибавлением или вычитанием единицы получится infinity или -infinity соответственно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое большое конечное число вычислить можно. Оно будет так велико, что его сумма с единицей будет равна ему самому. Этот критерий негодится. Я найду самое большое конечное число. То есть такое число что если к нему что-то прибавить, то получится или само число (если прибавка мала), или бесконечность (если прибавка достаточно велика).

Бесконечность отличается от обычного числа тем что `inf == 2 * inf`. Стартуем с единицы, последовательно удваиваем число пока не получим бесконечность. Запоминаем предыдущее значение в качестве стартовой точки (`y`).

Шаг `z` равен половине `y`. Добавляем шаг к `y` пока сумма конечна. Затем уменьшаем шаг в два раза и повторяем процесс. Останавливаемся в момент когда `y == y + z`. Для конечного `y` это условие означает что `z` так мало в сравнении с `y` что точности не хватает. В итоге в `y` лежит конечное число настолько большое, что к нему нельзя добавить никакую степень двойки.

Вся арифметика в программе точная - округления нет нигде кроме момента когда `y == y + z`. А в этот момент вычисления завершаются.

```
const max_finite = () => {
    let x;
    let y;
    for (x = 1; x != 2 * x; x *= 2) {
        y = x;
    } 
    const inf = x;
    for (let z = y / 2; z + y > y; z /= 2) {
        for (; y + z < inf; y += z) {
        }
    }
    return y;
};

console.log(max_finite());
```

> ```
> $ node max_finite.js
> 1.7976931348623157e+308
> ```

Comment: Как я понял это максимальное значение для правой границы, как будет выглядеть поиск левой границы?

Comment: @Vavilonium, минимальное положительное или минимальное отрицательное?

Comment: минимальное положительное

Comment: Делить единицу пополам, пока не обнулится. Последний не ноль - минимум.

Comment: `
function min_limit(min){
    step=1.0
    while (min - min/2 != min)
    {
        min /= 2;
    }
    return min;
}
`
Получился такой код со значением 5е-324, это правильно?

Comment: `while (min / 2 !== 0)`

Comment: Да, так же вышло значение 5е-324, но у меня такой вопрос, делал по аналогии c Python и вышло такое же значение для минимальной границы, но функция sys.float_info говорит что минимум для float в Python 2.2250738585072014e-308, как быть?

Comment: Разница тут: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0. `sys.float_info` выдаёт минимальное точно представленное число. Способ с делением выдаёт минимальное денормированное число.